# heatspreader paste on cpu pins

Tags: cpu, motherboard, heatsink

Recently, I tried to upgrade my AMD Ryzen CPU in my computer with a newer (compatible) one. When I removed the heatsink, it stuck to the old processor so strongly, that I quite possibly damaged the mainboard's CPU socket when extracting.

At least that's what I think what happened, as the computer won't start up with the new CPU and the CPU-error LED on the mainboard is lit.
Re-inserting the old CPU shows the same problem, which would confirm this.

Now for my actual problem: I bought a new mainboard and would (obviously) want to use my new CPU with this. However, during the removal of the new CPU from the heatsink, I got a really very small but noticeable bit of (non-conductive) heatspreader paste onto the pins of the CPU.
Should I clean it to avoid damage to the new mainboard socket? If yes, with what? My idea was to use alcohol on a toothbrush - is that a good idea or will it do more damage than good?

Comment: 99% isopropyl alcohol would be the only I could recommend but those pins are extremely fragile.  It’s not clear how you got thermal paste on the pins on the opposite side of a processor.  If you use a toothbrush I guarantee you will damage your processor. The pins are extremely fragile, if you bend the pins, you will have another paper weight

Comment: I would give it to a professional. By your own admittance you have ham-fistedly got the job wrong twice already. Why go for three in a row?

Comment: I'm usually not that clumsy and I have successfully changed CPUs before. This time however, I just did it in a stupidly unnecessary rush. And considering that the last time I gave my computer to a "professional", he did an even worse job than I usually do myself, I'd still rather give it one more go.
@Ramhound: Thanks, isopropanol and a bit of gentleness it's going to be then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for closure: I *did* use a toothbrush soaked in alcohol to clean between the pins. But really, really gently in a circling motion.
It worked perfectly, the CPU is now running happily in a new mainboard.